# How can I auto set height of one div based on other div element?

Tags: html, css

I have following code:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='left-child"'></div>
    <div class="right-child"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, if height of "left-child" is going to increase then height of "right-child" is also going to increase.

This might be a simple question as I'have less knowledge of html and css.

I don't want to use any of the java script code. 
I want only css and html code for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wEdjP/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The most cross-browsers solution is styling your divs with table properties. This is also the least semantic solution.

```
.parent{
     display:table;   
}
.parent > div {
     display:table-cell;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4dru/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the illusion of the left and right child having the same height, by adding the background you want to use in the right column to `.parent`. I've added an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3MCzm/